# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library: {...}.dll already loaded in another class loader

Tags: java, matlab, tomcat, builder, matlab-deployment

I have been using MATLAB Builder JA. I have developed two projects using JA. If only one project is deployed in tomcat, it runs fine, but deploying the other project gives the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v714\bin\win32\BuilderJABootstrap.dll already loaded in another class loader
```

The following link : http://groups.google.com/group/ibm.software.websphere.application-server/browse_thread/thread/02f08709a504d5fb?pli=1 suggests to create a shared library and add it to the server's classloader list, but , I have no idea how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the class and .ddl in question in Tomcat's $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib directory instead of in the web applications.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat